# htaccess url forwarding to php file with and without trailing slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, hyperlink

I've been looking for something like this (that works of course) for YEARS now.  Would be great if someone could finally produce this code.

At the moment, I've been working with this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [NC]
```

And it works great but doesn't work without a trailing slash.  And the annoying this is it treats all included files a folder forward so I am forever adding `../` to all css and js files.

Apart from the above, it works like this (as intended):

1. if www is not present, this will get added
2. http://www.example.com/page.php will go to page.php
3. http://www.example.com/page/ will go to page.php
4. http://www.example.com/page will come up with a 404 error as it's looking for the folder

I've tried loads of different things by Googling it but have had no success.  All I need it to do is to like the url without the trailing slash, whether it forwards it to a trailing slash that way or whether it likes both.  The whole idea is for it to read a .php file and display it in the window as a nice SEO type link: www.example.com/page

Comment: `^(.*)\/$` <-- Your pattern specifies that the URL must end in a forward slash!

Comment: When I remove this, I get an internal server error

Comment: That's because `^(.*)$` will match everything and thus an infinite loop of appending `.php` to the path will happen over and over again.  The easiest way around that is probably to use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` so that the rewrite will only happen if the path does not exist.

Comment: When I add that, neither pages are found when you're looking for `/page` or `/page/` however when you type in `/page.php` the error 404 says it was looking for `/page.php.php`

Comment: When I change it to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` it works great as `/page.php` and `/page` but an internal server error happens with `/page/`

Comment: I think we're getting somewhere!

Comment: And the good news about the link without the trailing slash is that you don't have to move all the include files back a directory. So ideally, now we need a rewrite that changes any `/page/` to `/page` before what we've got at the moment.

Comment: Okay, so just to clarify, I have this so far:

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]  

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>

Which works GREAT! Just the very last thing to do is to make sure /page/ is set to the folder back before that so /page and /page/...

Comment: are the same in terms of directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works. Answers this question.  Can anyone improve this?

Comment: I would quite like to have a custom 404 page directed to /404.php but the Rewrite rule kind of doesn't let that happen but the thing is, if I remove that, I get an internal sever error.